# Separating a list into different lists excel by category

Tags: excel

I have a list that currently looks like this:

[image]

I want to write something that automatically separates the list different lists based on the category column, that would create something like this:

[image]

Vlookup doesn't work as there are multiple values for each column. I could sort and extract, like i did for purposes of the picture above, but of course would prefer not to.

I'm trying to set up a system to "brain dump" all the things I need to do for the week and have it automatically organize itself by category. From there I plan to add a "priority" column by category...

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a code for me service.  Please provide in the original Post, not the comments, what you have tried.  Also whether you are looking for a formula answer or vba answer.  If vba you will need to provide any attempt of the code you have.

Comment: Please mark an answer correct if this accomplished your intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want to use a VBA macro. This is actually fairly simple. Essentially, we are going to set a destination column for each category. It is possible to do this dynamically for variable categories, but I'm going to assume they're constant for you. We go through each item in your first list and copy its value to the proper destination column, while using End(xlUp) to find the last populated data row and adding one to get the destination row.

```
Sub sortDescrip()
Dim destCol1, destCol2 As String

For Row = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case Range("A" & Row).Value
        Case "A"
            destCol1 = "E"
            destCol2 = "F"
        Case "B"
            destCol1 = "H"
            destCol2 = "I"
        Case "C"
            destCol1 = "K"
            destCol2 = "L"
        Case "D"
            destCol1 = "N"
            destCol2 = "O"
        Case Else
            destCol1 = "Q"
            destCol2 = "R"
    End Select
    lastRow = Range(destCol1 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range(destCol1 & lastRow).Value = Range("A" & Row).Value
    Range(destCol2 & lastRow).Value = Range("B" & Row).Value
Next
End Sub
```

I assume you have had little experience with VBA programs, and this should get you started thinking about them. Excel is powerful on its own, but it doesn't let you set the value of a non-selected cell, which VBA does. While I am happy to provide some intro code, @ScottCraner is right that you should go out on your own to get some base-level experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula, changing the category letter as required and copy down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15="A",ROW($A$1:$A$15)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15="A",ROW($A$1:$A$15)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Note that array formulas have to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than *just* <kbd>Enter</kbd>